# About the join method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

In the following code, the main thread will call `join()`, and the main thread will wait the sub thread finish and print the result `9`.

My question is the `join()` will make other thread wait until this thread finish. However, the main thread will call `join` but why it will wait until sub thread finish???

```
public class Starter extends Thread{
  private int x = 2;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    new Starter().makeItSo();
  }

  public Starter(){
    x = 5;
    start();
  }
  public void makeItSo() throws Exception{
    join(); // ??????
    x = x - 1;
    System.out.println(x);
  }
  public void run(){x *= 2;}
}
```

The following code is my understanding about the `join()`, the main thread will wait until t finish.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadDemo());
// this will call run() function
t.start();
// waits for this thread to die
t.join();
System.out.println("Hello");
```

Comment: `join` will make the CURRENT (calling) thread wait until the OTHER thread completes.  It's all about the context.  `makeItSo` is called within the context of the "main thread", which will cause it to wait until the `Starter` thread has completed

Comment: What would have if you changed instead it read something like `new Starter().join()`?  This is essentially what is happening in your code

Comment: According to the documentation for `join`: "Waits for this thread to die." The code after the `join` method is called won't execute until `run()` has executed. `Starter` is a thread, so calling `join()` in the `Starter` class causes it to wait until it's finished running.

Comment: You should pose one specific question and change the title to that question.  It is currently quite vague determining what you want to know here.

Comment: @MadProgrammer In my ThreadDemo() sample in the bottom, since main thread is the current thread and t is the other thread, the main thread will until the t finish. Is my understanding right? But what does the `calling` keyword mean in your answer?

Comment: @LoveTW that is absolutely correct and I show that in my answer.

Comment: @LoveTW When you call `makeItSo`, the method is executed/called within the current or main thread.  You could use `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().hashCode())` to print out the hash code of the current thread in both `makeItSo` and `run`

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, Lucas Baizer, Alain O'Dea, and Kenney.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important issue here is that **start()** must NOT be called in the constructor as it violates the Java Memory Model and exposes you to undefined behavior.

**this** inside **makeItSo()** is the  **Starter** instance so **join()** should make the main thread wait until **run()** finishes.

I do not see any race opportunities, but calling **start()** inside a **Thread** constructor violates the Java Memory Model by exposing an unsafe references to both **this** (of **Starter**) and **x** to the other thread.  You are now exposed to undefined behavior which is very bad and incredibly hard to debug.

The effective sequence of statements would intuitively be:

```
int x = 2;
x = 5;
x *= 2;
x = x - 1;
System.out.println(x);
```

And that would print **9** every time, but that is **NOT** guaranteed because the Java Memory Model has been violated so that behavior becomes probable at best rather than certain.

Don't call **start()** from a **Thread**'s constructor.  For more information see Brian Goetz's developerWorks article on safe construction techniques:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html

Now for the other example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadDemo());
// this will call run() function
t.start();
// waits for this thread to die
t.join();
System.out.println("Hello");
```

will behave similarly to:

```
new ThreadDemo().run();
System.out.println("Hello");
```

Running **t.join()** will make the code running on thread **t** behave as if it were run sequentially inline.  **otherThread.join()** makes the calling thread wait for **otherThread** to finish executing.

For emphasis I repeat: the most important issue here is that **start()** must NOT be called in the constructor as it violates the Java Memory Model and exposes you to undefined behavior.

Comment: @LucasBaizer in the bottom example of using **join()** with a thread constructed with **new ThreadDemo()**.

Comment: You should run the code, the thread runs (and `run` is executed) before `makeItSo` completes, otherwise the answer would `4`, not `9` - or at least it was for me - but we might be seeing a race condition ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer is this comment about my answer? I don't address those issues there.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea Yeah, sorry, specifically *"is a non-started Thread instance so join() will check that the thread is alive and finding that it isn't, finish immediately"*. Based on my tests, `join` blocks until `run` completes and the answer is outputted as `9`, but I might be seeing a race condition as I added `System.out.println` statements to my code :P (ps- Even without the `println` statements, it prints `9`, so `run` must have run before `x = x - 1;` and the `println` statement in `makeItSo`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer weird. The only thread (other than GC and other JVM stuff) in **Starter** is the main thread. **start()** is never called so there should be no possibility of a race at all.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea `start` is called in the `constructor` of `Starter` :P

Comment: Wait a second. The constructor calls **start()**. I would actually take this code review to the parking lot for a brawl at this point. That is incredibly confusing.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea Didn't say it was well written ;)

Comment: I've partly addressed my confusion. I'm thinking it through again and will adjust further.

Answer (score 2):

You basic concept of what `join` is doing is correct, you're getting confused because `makeItSo` is calling `join`, but you don't seem to understand the context in which the method is been called/executed.

I've taken your code and used `Thread.currentThread().hashCode())` to print the hash code of the current thread in various methods, for example.

```
public class Starter extends Thread {

    private int x = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Main > " + Thread.currentThread().hashCode());
        new Starter().makeItSo();
    }

    public Starter() {
        x = 5;
        start();
    }

    public void makeItSo() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("makeItSo > " + Thread.currentThread().hashCode());
        join(); // ??????
        x = x - 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run > " + Thread.currentThread().hashCode());
        x *= 2;
    }
}
```

When I ran the code I got the following output

```
Main > 705927765
makeItSo > 705927765
run > 1870487130
9
```

As you can see, both, `Main` and `makeItSo` are been called in the same `Thread`, but `run` is in another `Thread`, this is why `join` waits till `Starter` has completed.

Something that might be easier to understand would be to use the `name`  property of the `Thread`, for example...

```
public class Starter extends Thread {

    private int x = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Main > " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        new Starter().makeItSo();
    }

    public Starter() {
        setName("Starter");
        x = 5;
        start();
    }

    public void makeItSo() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("makeItSo > " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        join(); // ??????
        x = x - 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run > " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        x *= 2;
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
Main > main
makeItSo > main
run > Starter
9
```

Remember, when you call `start` on `Thread`, a new thread is spawned and your code continues to execute within the current thread context and at some time in the future, `run` is called.

Comment: Thank you very much! You answer make my concept more clear.

Comment: Well that was a crazy one.  I need to reread JCIP.  I should have seen that immediately!

Comment: @AlainO'Dea I think the basic concept of your answer is correct, but you just missed that `start` in the constructor which lead you slightly off track - threading is fun :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's the killer with threads. One lurking thing can have shocking impact that breaks the expected Java code as written semantics.  I think better static analysis could forbid or warn when calling **start()** in a contructor like this.  In practice you almost never need to extend **Thread** because you can create a **Runnable**.  You can even use an **ExecutorService** with a **Callable** which is very nice because you can capture an exception from the other thread.

Comment: @MadProgrammer can I think `join()` is `this.join()`, and `this` is Starter's obj. Since `join()` is called in Main thread, it will wait `Starter` thread complete. Is it right?

Comment: @LoveTW Yes, it's all about the context of the caller

Answer (score -1):

Main thread waits for sub thread to finish. Here is the reason:-
The best practice to invoke wait method is by using a thread object reference.
So when main thread invokes `makeItSo()` method of Starter class ( which is a thread object ) , invoking `join()` implicitly makes main thread to wait till the Starter thread has completed.
Lets say if you comment out `start()` call in Constructor , join will return immediately as the thread has not yet started and so it will print 4.
I hope this clears picture.

Comment: "invoking `join()` implicitly makes main thread to wait till the Starter thread has completed." <= this is not true at all. Think about and revise. **join()** operates on **this** (an instance of **Starter** which is a subclass of **Thread** but is distinct from the current thread which calls **makeItSo()**.

Comment: The thread has been started, see the constructor, and the answer is `9` ;)

Comment: yeah . i just said in case u don't  start the thread , output would be 4.